# MeteorJS linkify content

Tags: meteor, hyperlink, xss

I am seeking for the proper way to linkify a string block with MeteorJS.
The goal is to prevent XSS vulnerabilities but also to keep the reactivty.

I am currently bulding a chat with MeteorJS. Each of the message in my template can be edited. I have already tried thoses solutions:

1- Linkify DOM node woth various jQuery plugins/custon regex `replace()` function. Problem is that the `onRendered` callback is fired once, so messages updated won't be linkified again.
2- Return linkified HTML content from a helper. Problem is that it expose the app to XSS vulneravilities, and with a sanitizing process, some text may be lost (i want to keep the whole text, to display HTML code as text for exanple)
3- Used an autorun conputation declared in the `onRendered` callback with the `Template.currentData()` reactive dependency. It ensure that the DOM node will be linkified at every message update, but problem is that old content added manually with jQuery will remain in the node.

So, is there a way to ensure reactivity but also to keep the whole text in place. The goal here is to allow people to send code as text via messages. Meteor Spacebars is already predenting basic XSS with the double curly brace notation `{{}}`.

Thanks,

wILL

Comment: Is markdown an option?

Comment: Well if it suits my need, it could be an option. I was thinking to add some text decoration capbilities in the future. Could you expand your idea with the pros/cons regarding my needs ?

Comment: The `markdown` meteor package will automatically linkify any url and allow for formatting. Using it is as simple as just wrapping your property in a spacebars wrapper `{{#markdown}}{{comment}}{{/markdown}}`

Comment: Sorry... I was under the impression that it automatically parsed links, but you have to wrap urls with parenthesis to make it a link. Disregard my idea.

Comment: That is also what i was thinking, but for example, this online markdown editor http://dillinger.io/ handle link parsing without parenthesis.

Comment: Also, github handle this. Is this a basic markdown feature or is it custom ? I would totally consider markdown if it can handle links without specific syntax, which is the main goal.

Comment: The `markdown` package is basically a wrapper for the [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/blob/master/src/showdown.js) library, which doesn't auto-link urls unless they're wrapped in `<>`  or the standard markdown syntax `[label](url)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like https://github.com/chuangbo/meteor-marked is the good option. It handle bare links.